# ld: Assertion failed: (atom->fixupCount() == 1)

Tags: ios

I get an error when linking my static library (Strip style: Non-Global Symbols) to my iOS application for i386 architechture
Assertion failed: (atom->fixupCount() == 1)

The linking works fine when building for armv7 or armv7s so the problem only occurs for i386 (the emulator).

Xcode version: 4.5.2 (also tested with 4.6 (4H104c) - Preview)

Does anyone have a clue how to get around this problem?

```
0  0x10ecde098  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x10ecf33b2  mach_o::relocatable::ObjC2ClassRefsSection<x86>::targetClassName(mach_o::reloca table::Atom<x86> const*, ld::IndirectBindingTable const&) const + 136
2  0x10ecf3219  mach_o::relocatable::ObjC2ClassRefsSection<x86>::contentHash(mach_o::relocatabl e::Atom<x86> const*, ld::IndirectBindingTable const&) const + 9
3  0x10ecf141e  mach_o::relocatable::Atom<x86>::contentHash(ld::IndirectBindingTable const&) const + 42
4  0x10ed17d53  std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::pair<ld::Atom const*, unsigned int>, void*>*> std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::pair<ld::Atom const*, unsigned int>, std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<ld::Atom const*, unsigned int, ld::tool::SymbolTable::ReferencesHashFuncs, true>, std::__1::__unordered_map_equal<ld::Atom const*, unsigned int, ld::tool::SymbolTable::ReferencesHashFuncs, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<ld::Atom const*, unsigned int> > >::find<ld::Atom const*>(ld::Atom const* const&) + 37
5  0x10ed1713f  ld::tool::SymbolTable::findSlotForReferences(ld::Atom const*, ld::Atom const**) + 111
6  0x10ed1b7b6  ld::tool::Resolver::convertReferencesToIndirect(ld::Atom const&) + 124
7  0x10ed1b59e  ld::tool::Resolver::doAtom(ld::Atom const&) + 802
8  0x10ecf4e56  mach_o::relocatable::File<x86>::forEachAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&) const + 54
9  0x10ed1476c  ld::tool::InputFiles::forEachInitialAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&) + 420
10  0x10ed1d884  ld::tool::Resolver::resolve() + 44
11  0x10ecde380  main + 370
12  0x10eccfcd4  start + 52
A linker snapshot was created at:
          /tmp/EncapUI-2012-11-12-170500.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (atom->fixupCount() == 1), function targetClassName, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-136/src/ld/parsers/macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 4973.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Neat, you got the linker to fail an assert... I would take a look at that linker snapshot. See if there are any clues to what the problematic Atom might be.